# Implement multi preferred parent in rpl protocol using Contiki OS

Tags: c, contiki

I try to implement multi-parent rpl protocol, i use Contiki 3.0.

From the **rpl-dag.c** file there is **static rpl_parent_t *
best_parent(rpl_dag_t *dag)** function, it send two neighbors to **static rpl_parent_t *best_parent(rpl_parent_t *p1, rpl_parent_t *p2)** function in **mrhof.c** file and this function return the best neighbor to be prefered one.

What i trying to do is to get the other neighbor (not the best) and compare it with all other nighbers so i get the best two neighbor, but when function in **mrhof.c** return one prefered parent i cant know which is this neighbor as you can see in this line in **rpl-dag.c** file:

> *best* = dag->instance->of->best_parent(**best**, ***p***);

I mean in this line the function send **best** and ***p*** and get the *best* one of them but i cant know which one is chosen as best so i can take the other and compare it with other neighbors.

And if i try to send three neighbor to function in **mrhof.c** i should return two best like this **return best1, best2** but this of course does not work.

Answer (score 0):

One option is that you introduce a new parameter in the parent selection algorithm: the parent to ignore. Then you can do the parent selection two times. The first time with the "ignore parameter" set to NULL, the second time with "ignore parameter" set to the parent find in the first time NULL.

Code for the main idea:

```
rpl_parent_t *best1 = NULL;
rpl_parent_t *best2 = NULL;
best1 = best_parent(NULL);
if(best1 != NULL) {
  best2 = best_parent(best1);
}
```

Where the selection is done as:

```
rpl_parent_t *best_parent(rpl_parent_t *to_ignore)
{
  rpl_parent_t *best = NULL;
  rpl_parent_t *p;
  for(p = nbr_table_head(rpl_parents); p != NULL; p = nbr_table_next(rpl_parents, p)) {
    if(p != to_ignore) {
      best = of->best_parent(best, p);
    }
  }
  return best;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but i don't understand the value of to_ignore it set to NULL initially then it compare with best one like this: best1 = dag->instance->of->best_parent(to_ignore, NULL ); best2=dag->instance->of->best_parent(best1, to_ignore);  but the value of to_ignore is still NULL so best2 will compare best1 to NULL also, why?, and all changed done in best_parent of rpl-dag.c file not in mrhof.c file, am i correct?

Comment: Yes, in `rpl-dag.c`. I don't understand the first part of your comment.

Comment: I mean what is the value of to_ignore? , code for the main idea never assign value to to_ignore so what is the value of to_ignore?

Comment: It does assign a value to `to_ignore`. Read the code again.